# Convert multiple varchars to datetime, ignoring errors, or handling them as a batch

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find a way to convert a while row of varchars in to datetime's, without doing it in a loop.

Say I have a table:

```
dateText varchar(20),
dateDate dateTime
```

Where the `dateText` field is filled with dates in the format of `20140506` (`yyyyMMdd`). I'd like to populate the `dateDate` field with conversions, but ignore any errors that occur. So if one fails, I don't want the entire operation to fail.

Is it possible to carrying out an update ignoring errors for the rows it fails on??

**EDIT:**
I had thought the ISDATE command was not working for me, but upon double checking (thanks to Gordons comment below) it seems I probably just had a typo. So this can be done with something to the effect of:

```
update mytable
set dateDate = case when ISDATE(dateText) = 1
                    then convert(dateText)
                    else //do something else or ignore
```

Comment: Why don't you think that `isdate()` works on "yyyymmdd" formats?

Comment: Well, because I tried it.. however this might be the part where I realise I made a typo the first time around, as going back to double check is giving me a different answer! I am still interested to whether an update of the above can be done ignoring errors though, I'll update the question.

Comment: Your approach seems okay to me. You can quickly test it out, by simply making a small test table and run it. Also FYI - if dateText is in yyyyMMdd format, you do not even need to 'convert' it in your "then". SQL Server can parse it implicit.